# Feasibility of Matrix Inequality

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I need to show if the following inequality is true

$$ (A + B)^{-1}M (A + B)^{-1} - A^{-1} M A^{-1} \preceq 0$$

given that $(A,B)=(A^T,B^T) \succ 0$ and $M = M^T \succeq 0$ also we have that $A + B \succeq A$. If $M = I$, then, it is pretty clear that the above inequality holds, but can we find conditions on $A$ such that the above holds for any PSD $M$?

Comment: Feasibility means that a condition or set of conditions *can be* satisfied.  Are you asking about that, or are you asking if the inequality is *necessarily* satisfied in all cases?  You've also used the word "optimization" without specifying an objective function to maximize or minimize.

Comment: What is your definition of PSD matrices? If your require a PSD matrix to be Hermitian, then $(A+B)^{-1}M(A+B)^{-1}M$ is not Hermitian in general.

Comment: @user1551 I am sorry, but there should not be an $M$ at the end. had a silly typo...sorry about that....these matrices are all real so ok with symmetric...are you saying that the inequality would never be satisfied for any $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true. When $M=I$, it reduces to $(A+B)^{-2}\preceq A^{-2}$ or equivalently, $A^2\preceq (A+B)^2$. So it's essentially saying that $0\preceq X\preceq Y$ implies $X^2\preceq Y^2$, which is false in general (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999) for a counterexample).

Comment: thank you for your reply. But, since I have the condition that $A + B \succeq A$, then, for the case $M=I$, I do have $(A+B)^2 \succeq B^2$ and so the inequality holds? is that correct? I believe that the $M$ is causing problems in my case so I wanted to find conditions on $A$ such that the inequality would hold for any $M = M^T \succeq 0$

Comment: @user2457324 No. Call $A+B$ as $X$ and $B$ as $Y$. You are saying that $X\succeq Y$ implies that $X^2\succeq Y^2$. As the linked answer shows, this is wrong.

Comment: thank you so much for this. Would it be possible for you to provide any insights on the structure of $X,Y$ for why the implication does not hold for higher powers? e.g., something regarding the kernel of some combination of $X,Y$ -- though these are non-zero since it is PD...it would really help me if I could get a mathematical reason why this doesn't hold. hopefully this kind of makes sense. thanks again.

Comment: Also, would you be able to give me any citation of the above in a text, for example? I could not find this in Bernestein's book....your counter is great though :) thanks again and any thoughts (if a precise answer is not clear -- e.g., what you think in the structure may be the culprit) on my previous comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user2457324 The keyword here is "operator monotone". It is actually well-known that among all nonnegative exponent $p$, the power function $t\mapsto t^p$ is operator monotone if and only if $0\le p\le1$. In particular, every positive integer power (except the identity map) will **not** preserve the positive semidefinite partial ordering. E.g. see prop. 2.4 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2471.pdf).

Comment: @user2457324 I haven't any references at hand. I seem to recall that some papers of Horn/Johnson has an even more refined result, but I couldn't find it right now. You may also consult Horn and Johnson's *Topics in Matrix Analysis* or Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* to see if they have documented this result or not.

Comment: Hi -- I was wondering if you would be able to help me with the Q here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279926/understanding-the-kernel-space-of-the-differences-of-transition-matrices
thank you!