# Do we have $\|A\|_F\leq \|B\|_F$ if $-B\preceq A\preceq B$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

In the question, $A$ is a symmetric matrix, and $B$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. $A\preceq B$ means that $B-A$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. $\|\|_F$ means the Frobenius norm.

Comment: This would be easy if we could conclude that $A^2 \preceq B^2$, but notably [we cannot](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999/81360)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Suppose without loss of generality (via the spectral theorem) that $A$ is diagonal, so that its (real) diagonal entries are $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, and its other entries are zero. *(In other words: if the orthogonal $U$ is such that $U^TAU$ is diagonal, we now consider $U^TAU$ instead of $A$ and $U^TBU$ instead of $B$)*

We have $-B \preceq A \preceq B$, which tells us that both $B + A$ and $B - A$ are positive semidefinite.  Thus, the diagonal entries $(B+A)_{ii} = B_{ii} + \lambda_i$ and $(B - A)_{ii} = B_{ii} - \lambda_i$ are necessarily non-negative.  Thus, $B_{ii} > |\lambda_i|$.  Thus, we have
$$
\|B\|_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} B_{ij}^2 \geq \sum_{i} B_{ii}^2 \geq \sum_{i}\lambda_i^2  = \|A\|_F^2
$$
as desired.