# If $A, B, A^2-B^2$ are positive definite prove that $A-B$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

If $A, B, A^2-B^2$ are real symmetric positive definite matrices, prove that $A-B$ is also positive definite .

Comment: @kotomord but we don't have AB=BA

Comment: One answer is given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510895/if-a2-succ-b2-then-necessarily-a-succ-b/510999#510999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M> 0$ mean that $M$ is positive definite. We have 
$$
A^2 - B^2 > 0 \implies\\
A^{-1}(A^2 - B^2)A^{-1} > 0 \implies\\
I - A^{-1}B^2A^{-1} > 0  
$$
Thus, $A^{-1}B^2A^{-1} = (BA^{-1})^T(BA^{-1})$ is positive definite with eigenvalues strictly less than $1$. Since the spectral norm $\|BA^{-1}\|$ is at most $1$, conclude that the eigenvalues of $BA^{-1}$ are all at most $1$ (in absolute value).

Thus, the matrix $A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} = A^{-1/2}(BA^{-1})A^{1/2}$ is positive definite with eigenvalues at most $1$.  Thus, we have
$$
I - A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} > 0  \implies\\
A^{1/2}(I - A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})A^{1/2} > 0 \implies\\
A - B > 0
$$
which was the desired conclusion.

Comment: Hello, what if we have $A,B,A-B$ non-negative definite matrix (which means we may not have $A^{-1}$) , can we have $\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}$ also is non-negative definite matrix? Thanks.

Comment: @hctb yes, that's equivalent to the question you asked here.  If you want to know more, perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2101727/190802 ok i posted it:p

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A^{1/2}$ to be the Hermitian square root of $A$ and $\rho$ to be the spectral radius.

Hint: $A^2-B^2>0$ $\Leftrightarrow$  $I-A^{-1}BBA^{-1}>0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\|BA^{-1}\|<1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rho(BA^{-1})<1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\rho(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})<1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $I-A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}>0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $A-B>0$.

Try to work out all the implications.