# assume we have $A,B,A-B$ non-negative definite matrix…

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Assume we have real symmetric $A,B,A-B$ non-negative definite matrix , how to prove $\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}$ also is non-negative definite matrix? Where $\sqrt{A}$ is the only symmetric non-negative definite matrix satisfy $X^2=A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt{A},\sqrt{B},$ and $\sqrt{A}^2 - \sqrt{B}^2$ are positive semidefinite.  Then, apply the arguments from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016527/if-a-b-a2-b2-are-positive-definite-prove-that-a-b-is-positive-definite/2016711?noredirect=1#comment4321482_2016711).