# Squares of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose $L_1  \succeq L_2$, where $L_1,L_2$ are positive semidefinite matrices (actually combinatorial Laplacians). Is the following inequality true, and if no, under which conditions?

$$L_1^2  \succeq L_2^2$$

Comment: The answer for general PSD matrices is "no". See [If $A^2\succ B^2$, then necessarily $A\succ B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510895/if-a2-succ-b2-then-necessarily-a-succ-b). Need to think about the Laplacian case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not always true. Counterexample:
$$
\begin{align*}
&L_1=\pmatrix{1&-1&0\\ -1&2&-1\\ 0&-1&1},
\ L_2=\pmatrix{1&-1&0\\ -1&1&0\\ 0&0&0},\\
&L_1^2-L_2^2=\pmatrix{0&-1&1\\ -1&4&-3\\ 1&-3&2}.
\end{align*}
$$
I'm not sure if there is any good (non-restrictive) sufficient condition for the inequality to hold.

Answer (score 0):

It is also not true in general in the $2\times 2$ case: consider for instance 
$$
L_1=\begin{bmatrix} 3&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ \ L_2=\begin{bmatrix}4&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
L_2^2-L_1^2=\begin{bmatrix} 11&16\\16&20\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is not positive semidefinite.