# Squaring matrices and positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, symmetric, $n\times n$ real matrices such that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. Write $A\succeq B$. **When** is it true that $A^2\succeq B^2$?

---

I know given the conditions, $A^2\succeq B^2$ is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999/178464) in general. On the other hand, let $u_1\geq\ldots\geq u_n\geq 0$ and $v_1\geq\ \ldots \geq v_n\geq 0$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. By the [Min-Max Principle](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~loss/16FALLTEA/NOTES/minmax.pdf), we have
$$
u_i\geq v_i,\quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Then, $u_1^2\geq\ldots\geq u_n^2$ and $v_1^2\geq\ldots\geq v_n^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A^2$ and $B^2$ and satisfy
$$
u_i^2\geq v_i^2,\quad i=1,\ldots,n.\tag{$*$}
$$
I used to think that ($*$) would be enough to give $A^2\succeq B^2$ but as the counter-example linked above shows, it clearly doesn't. So I'm wondering how we can strengthen ($*$) to give $A^2\succeq B^2$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but thank you for mentioning the min-max principle. I learned something new.

Comment: $A^2\succeq B^2$ iff $Id\succeq A^{-1}BBA^{-1}$, which is equivalent to the singular values of $A^{-1}B$ being less or equal to 1.

Comment: @Daniel That sounds promising. Please feel free to develop that into an answer. Do you know how to relate the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$ to those of $A$ and of $B$?