# Spectral norm inequality product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

If $B \geq A \geq 0$ and $M \geq 0$ are real symmetric matrices, is it true that

$\| B M B \|_2 \geq \| A M A \|_2$ ?

Comment: Is $\| X \|_2 = \sqrt{\mathrm{Tr}[X^* X]}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999), for instance, that $B\ge A\ge0$ does not imply $B^2\ge A^2$. Now pick such a pair of real matrices $A$ and $B$. Then $u^T B^2u<u^T A^2u$ for some nonzero real vector $u$. Let $M=uu^T$. Then
$$
\|BMB\|_2= u^TB^2u<u^TA^2u=\|AMA\|_2.
$$