# If ${\bf A} - {\bf B}$ is positive semidefinite, then is ${\bf A}^{1/2} - {\bf B}^{1/2}$ still positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

For two real symmetric and positive semidefinite matrices, ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$, of same size, can we prove

${\bf A} \succeq {\bf B} \quad \iff \quad {\bf A}^{1/2} \succeq {\bf B}^{1/2}$,

where $\cdot^{1/2}$ denotes the square root of a matrix.

Comment: how do you define the square root for non-SPD matrices?

Comment: @Exodd, thanks, I have edited the conditions in my question.

Comment: It is true that $A \succeq B \implies A^{1/2} \succeq B^{1/2}$, but the converse $A^{1/2} \succeq B^{1/2} \implies A \succeq B$ does not hold. Both of these implications have been asked about on this site; see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999/81360) for example.