# Does $0\preceq A \preceq B$ imply $f(A) \preceq f(B)$ for concave(?) functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, positive-definite

It seems to be a fairly common exercise to show that
$$
0\preceq A \preceq B \implies \sqrt A \preceq \sqrt B
$$
for positive semi-definite matrices. On the other hand, in general,
$$
0\preceq A \preceq B \ \nRightarrow\ A^2 \preceq B^2.
$$
(See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/510999/620957).

Along with being able to take inverses, this is more or less the usual simple results I've seen of this kind. But do they hint at a more general theorem behind the scenes? I'm imaging some result along the lines of

> If $0\preceq A \preceq B$, and if $f$ is a [concave, increasing, positive, ...?] function, then $f(A)\preceq f(B)$.

I realize that this question is somewhat vague, so sorry about that, but is there a nice result to discovered here? My googling is being unsuccessful... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such an $f$ is called operator-monotone, and these were classified by Lowner. [See here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wner-Heinz_inequality)

Comment: Thank you, that's all I need then! I'll try to find a duplicate to close this question.

Comment: To other readers, https://doi.org/10.1155/2015/649839 seems to be a nice survey  on related results. (I'll look further for a suitable duplicate later).

Comment: Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* has a very nice chapter on operator-monotone and operator-convex functions for anyone interested. There is a condition that is a bit stronger than "concave" that is needed here, and that condition is "operator-concavity". For functions defined over $[0,\infty)$, the conditions of operator monotonicity and operator concavity are equivalent.